# Problem using personal AWS resources with an Alexa Hosted Skill

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm facing an issue accessing a DynamoDB table in my AWS account. I'm trying to connect to it, but whenever I attempt to save the name into the database, I consistently encounter an error message stating that an error has occurred and to try again later. What steps can I take to troubleshoot this? Below is the code I'm using:

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        
        // 1. Assume the AWS resource role using STS AssumeRole Action
        const STS = new AWS.STS({ apiVersion: '2011-06-15' });
        
        let speechText = "";
        const credentials = await STS.assumeRole({
            RoleArn: '<MY ARN FROM THE ROLE>',
            RoleSessionName: 'ExampleSkillRoleSession' // You can rename with any name
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                speechText += "Oops! Something went wrong.";
                console.log('AssumeRole FAILED: ', err);
                throw new Error('Error while assuming role');
            }
            return res;
        }).promise();

        // 2. Make a new DynamoDB instance with the assumed role credentials
        //    and scan the DynamoDB table
        const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
            accessKeyId: credentials.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: credentials.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: credentials.Credentials.SessionToken
        });

            // 3. Construir el mensaje de bienvenida solicitando el nombre del usuario
            speechText += "Hello, please tell me your name.";

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speechText)
                .reprompt(speechText)
                .getResponse();
    }
};

const DarNombreIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'DarNombreIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const {attributesManager} = handlerInput;
        const requestAttributes = attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
        const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        const {intent} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        
        // Obtener el nombre del usuario del slot 'UserNameSlot' de la solicitud
        const userId = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userId;
        const userName = intent.slots.nombre.value;
        // Crear una instancia del cliente DynamoDB
        const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

        try {
            // Guardar el nombre del usuario en la tabla DynamoDB
            await dynamoDB.put({
                TableName: 'InscripcionesAsignaturas',
                Item: {
                    'user_id': userId,
                    'user_name': userName
                }
            }).promise();

            // Construir el mensaje de bienvenida
            const speechText = "Thank you, ${userName}. How can I assist you?";

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speechText)
                .reprompt(speechText)
                .getResponse();
        } catch (error) {
            // Manejar errores si ocurren al guardar en la tabla DynamoDB
            console.error('Error saving to DynamoDB table:', error);
            const speechText = "Sorry, an error occurred. Please try again later.";

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
        }
    }
};
```

I want the name to be successfully saved in the database. I've followed all the steps outlined in the 'Use Personal AWS Resources with Your Alexa-Hosted Skill' guide regarding the creation of the IAM role and adding the Alexa skill ARN to the role.

Comment: Please include the exact error message that you received. That way, it will be easier for us to help identify the problem. Good luck!